# gcloud beta command in build step in cloudbuild.yaml. Should I use entrypoint or args?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, beta, cloudbuild.yaml

I'm trying to build and deploy a Docker image to Cloud Run. And I'd like to set `min-instances=1` so I can avoid cold starts.

I'm building and deploying it using Cloud Build through the `gcloud` CLI.

So this is was my 1st attempt from the `gcloud` CLI:

```
gcloud builds submit . --config=./cloudbuild.yaml
```

And here are the build steps that are described in my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
  # STEP_1: DOCKER BUILDS IMAGE
  # STEP_2: DOCKER PUSHES IMAGE TO CLOUD REGISTRY

  # STEP_3: GCLOUD SHOULD DEPLOY TO CLOUD RUN (DESCRIBED BELOW)

  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "my-service"
      - "--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image"
      - "--platform=managed"
      - "--region=us-central1"
      - "--min-instances=1"
```

You see that the build `STEP_3` runs: `gcloud run deploy my-service ... min-instances=1`

And I'm getting the following error:

```
The `--min-instances` flag is not supported in the GA release track on the 
fully managed version of Cloud Run. Use `gcloud beta` to set `--min-instances` on Cloud Run (fully managed).
```

So I guess I'll have to use `gcloud beta` commands. But I have some questions in that case:

Do I also need to add the `beta` command to my `gcloud builds submit .` command?

And how should I set it in `cloudbuilt.yaml`? Do I add it to the `entrypoint` or as an argument in `args`?

**OPTION #1**

```
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: "gcloud beta"
    args:
      - "run"
   // ETC
```

**OPTION #2**

```
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - "beta"
      - "run"
   // ETC
```

Comment: Use under args. All the elements are concatenated into a string.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing like a hidden reason for either.

Use under args. All the elements are concatenated into a string.